# get distinct values for not unique index indexedDb

Tags: indexeddb

in rDBMS you can `select DISTINCT value` on indexed column of relation. It is supposed to **scan INDEX only** to reduce I/O and time.

**Question**: How do I do same in indexedDb?

**Research**: I know mongodb does it, but I can't find any info for indexedDb for this. I expected [getAllKeys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBIndex/getAllKeys) would help, but it lists PK values only for me. My case? Imagine a store with a million rows. One column is EU country and it is indexed. Distribution is very variable for every country. I want to get rows for one country (There can be no rows for one country and much for other). I give user ability to perform search per country. But he has plenty of "empty" buttons - country code with no rows. Instead I want to give him county codes that exist in Store. So I do this:

```
        var k = objstore.index("ISO");
        var r = k.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.bound("A", "Z"));
        var disp = [];
        r.onsuccess = function(e) {
            var cursor = e.target.result;
            if(cursor) {
                disp[cursor.key] = (disp[cursor.key] || 0) + 1 ;
                cursor.continue();
                } else {
            console.log(disp);
        }
```

But it is slow. And it operates on the whole Store (it least it looks so - I consume `e.target.result.key` while `value` is available as well. This reminds me IOT behaviour, but not an index...

Anyway, who knows just tell me - can I use index wanted way?..

I'm a rDBMS guy new to IndexedDb. Sorry if I talk complete nonsence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe using a parameter to [IDBCursor.prototype.continue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBCursor/continue) will help you do what you want? You can pass in the next key you want to find as an additional parameter.

Or, you can also try passing a direction parameter to [IDBIndex.prototype.openCursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBIndex/openCursor), such as "nextunique". In this case, "The cursor shows all records, excluding duplicates. If multiple records exist with the same key, only the first one iterated is retrieved. It starts at the lower bound of the key range and moves upwards."